# Include section of existing drawing in a new Asymptote file

Tags: include, asymptote

Experts,

I have created a drawing using Asymptote. Now I would like to include a specific section of this drawing in a new .asy-File to make it larger and add some additional lines. Is there a smart way to do this or will I have to copy-paste the code and leave out all the lines I don't want to display?

I make a simple example to clarify.
The original drawing looks like this:

```
unitsize(1cm);
size(10cm);

draw(unitcircle);
draw((-5, 0) -- (5, 0));
draw((0, -5) -- (0, 5));
```

I would like to include this code in a new file and specify to show only the top right section.

Thanks for the advice!

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your requirement precisely, but
`\includegraphics*[trim=a b c d]{image}`
discards a, b, c, d bps from left, lower, right,
and upper parts, respectively:
`\documentclass{article}`
`\usepackage{graphicx}`
`\begin{document}`
`\includegraphics*[trim=142 142 0 0]{your-sample.eps}`
`\end{document}`

Comment: Hello, trimming the image would work for me, but I was wondering if there is a similar command in Asymptote so I can add lines and shapes on top of the trimmed image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `clip` function in `asymptote`.  You give the `clip` command a path and anything previously drawn outside that path will be clipped away.  The `size` command is not needed here.

```
unitsize(1cm);
// size(10cm);

draw(unitcircle);
draw((-5, 0) -- (5, 0));
draw((0, -5) -- (0, 5));

clip(shift(-0.5,-0.5)*scale(5.5)*unitsquare);
draw(shift(3,3)*unitcircle, red); // new stuff after clipping
```

[image]

Now, if you want this section to be drawn larger, just edit the `unitsize` command.

```
unitsize(2cm);
//size(10cm);

draw(unitcircle);
draw((-5, 0) -- (5, 0));
draw((0, -5) -- (0, 5));

clip(shift(-0.5,-0.5)*scale(5.5)*unitsquare);

draw(shift(3,3)*unitcircle, red);
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I was not aware of the clip function. Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome!  The usual way to thank someone on this site is to up-vote their answer.  You can do this by clicking the upward facing pen nib above the green checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: I will do this as soon as I have 15 reputation. It does not allow me right now ;)

Comment: Additional note: `include foo;` has the effect of including all the code of `foo.asy` into the current file (including code you may not want, such as a no-longer applicable `size` or `unitsize` command).